# incluir tag e categoria nos resultados de busca wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá, gostaria de incluir tags e categorias nos resultados de busca ou seja, ao digitar no formulário a categoria CABELO gostaria que aparecesse todas os posts dessa categoria.

Eu estava usando o código abaixo:( Mas percebi que as paginas é que somem dos resultados de busca).

Sou nova com wp faz 3 dias que procuro essa resolução, caso alguém tenha alguma dica agradeço muito.

Segue o código :

```
function atom_search_where($where){
  global $wpdb;
  if (is_search())
    $where .= "OR (t.name LIKE '%".get_search_query()."%' AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish')";
  return $where;
}

function atom_search_join($join){
  global $wpdb;
  if (is_search())
    $join .= "LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = tr.object_id INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id";
  return $join;
}

function atom_search_groupby($groupby){
  global $wpdb;


  $groupby_id = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
  if(!is_search() || strpos($groupby, $groupby_id) !== false) return $groupby;


  if(!strlen(trim($groupby))) return $groupby_id;


  return $groupby.", ".$groupby_id;
}

add_filter('posts_where','atom_search_where');
add_filter('posts_join', 'atom_search_join');
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'atom_search_groupby');
```

Comment: Mas o Wordpress já não faz isso? Não entendi qual é o problema.

Comment: OMG, você salvou minha vida com esse plugin "search everything" eu te amoooo

Answer (score 1):

Não sei porque essa pergunta apareceu pra mim hoje, mas ela tem mais de 200 views e não tem resposta pra uma coisa razoavelmente simples que é bem útil, então lá vai:

Não é preciso usar `$wpdb` e mexer nas cláusulas do SQL pra isso, basta usar o hook [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts) e alterar a query principal:

```
<?php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modifica_busca' );

function modifica_busca( $query ) {

    // pre_get_posts é chamada diversas vezes numa requisição
    // então precisamos conferir se estamos na chamada pricipal da busca
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
        $termo_de_busca = get_search_query();

        // busca se a palavra digitada confere com alguma categoria
        // taxonomy pode ser trocada por post_tag ou outra taxonomia
        $taxonomy = 'category';
        $cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $termo_de_busca, $taxonomy );

        // se o termo de busca não existe como termo de uma 
        // taxonomia, retorna e finaliza a busca aqui
        if ( ! $cat ) {
            return;
        }

        // remove o termo de busca pra que a busca não inclua somente
        // os posts que tem a palavra no titulo ou conteudo
        $query->set( 's', '' );

        // busca outras consultas por taxonomia que podem existir
        $tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' );

        // adiciona a nossa
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'field' => 'slug',
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'terms' => $termo_de_busca,
        );

        // adiciona a busca completa de volta à consulta principal
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
```

Comment: Aonde coloco esse código ?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que por padrão o wordpress só irá procurar o título e o conteúdo de um post.Talvez esse plugin ajude :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/

Eu estava com esse problema e só consegui com o plugin.

Mas caso não queira usar plugin pode dar uma olhada nesse outro usuário que está com a mesma dúvida :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407928/posts-from-category-not-displaying-when-searching-for-category-name