# Fazer categorias aparecer nos resultados de buscas no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Por exemplo, Eu pesquiso PAGODE na busca, acima dos resultados dos posts aparece também as categorias que tenha o nome PAGODE.

Tentei isso: [incluir tag e categoria nos resultados de busca wordpress](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76450/incluir-tag-e-categoria-nos-resultados-de-busca-wordpress)

mas não consegui. Alguém pra me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONSEGUI COM ESSE CODIGO!

```html
$search_term = explode( ' ', get_search_query( false ) );   
global $wpdb;
$select = "
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.* 
FROM wp_terms AS t 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt 
ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category')";      
$first = true;
foreach ( $search_term as $s ){
    if ( $first ){
        $select .= " AND (t.name LIKE '%s')";
        $string_replace[] = '%'.$wpdb->esc_like( $s ).'%';
        $first = false;
    }else{
        $select .= " OR (t.name LIKE '%s')";
        $string_replace[] = '%'. $wpdb->esc_like( $s ).'%';
    }
}
$select .= " ORDER BY t.name ASC";
$terms = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $select, $string_replace ) );
if ( count($terms) > 0 ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ).'" title="'.esc_attr( $term->name ).'">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa opção é instalar o plugin [Relevanssi](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/). Ele possui configurações para ajudar com o seu problema, e também melhora bastante a qualidade das buscas.